# Delete item in cart using checkbox on Magento

Tags: php, magento, controller, cart

I was tasked to create a functionality where you can delete chosen items using a checkbox.

this is my code that will run after clicking *"Delete selected items"*. 
**$to_delete** gets the product IDs that were checked.

```
public function _deleteItems(){
        $to_delete = $_POST['deleteItem'];

        foreach($to_delete as $item){
            $this->deleteAction($item);     
        }
    }
```

now... I shouldn't change anything in **deleteAction()**. How would I delete the items in the cart?

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got the code but wasn't able to use the **deleteAction()** method.

```
public function deleteItems(){
    $to_delete = $_POST['deleteItem'];


    $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
    $items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();

    foreach($to_delete as $product){
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $product) {
                $itemId = $item->getItemId();
                $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I was on the right track in getting the product ID but I didn't get the cart item ID of the product.

Hope this code helps someone out there!
Good luck.